# Associate instances of Designer and Component?

Tags: vb.net, attributes, components, designer

VB.NET under VS2008

I have created a component with a Designer attribute:

```
<Designer(GetType(MyComponentDesigner))> _
Public Class MyComponent
    (etc....)
```

It is my understanding that an instance of MyComponentDesigner will be created along with each instance of MyComponent.  Is this right?

If so, each instance of MyComponentDesigner needs to reference "its" MyComponent.  How?

(To clarify: one thing the Designer does is to implement a RMB "verb".  When a MyComponent user clicks that verb, the handler needs to call the specific instance of MyComponent that the user right-clicked to see the verb.)

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user (developer) can only edit one component at a time, there can ever only one actively being interacted with at a time.  Also, 'designer' is a broad term as there are MANY designer types, so part of the answer is "it depends".

When your designer needs a reference to the component being editted, NET passes a reference to it.  For instance, for SmartTags (inheriting `DesignerActionList`) the constructor is:

```
Sub New(ByVal component As IComponent)
    MyBase.New(component)
    m_Control = CType(component, myControl)
End Sub
```

The constructor for other UIEditors (like a collection editor) you dont get the reference in the constructor because you dont need it yet.  They might pass the component/context later:

```
  Protected Overrides Sub LoadValues(ByVal context _
         As ITypeDescriptorContext, _
         ByVal provider As System.IServiceProvider, ByVal value As Object)
```

When and how you get a reference to your component depends on which base editor type your designer will inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I have discovered MyComponentDesigner's Component property, which I can cast to MyComponent to get the reference I need.